# get_text() results to attribute error when there is no text in div class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract ratings using `get_text()` but get attribute error when there is no text in div class. Following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/exercise-fitness/fitness-equipment/home-gym-combos/pr?sid=qoc,amf,pz0&q=gym+equipments+combo+50+kg&otracker=categorytree')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find('div', class_='t-0M7P _2doH3V')

boxes = container.find_all('div', class_="_3liAhj")

for box in boxes:
    title = box.find(class_='_2cLu-l').get_text()
    print(title)
    rating = box.find(class_='hGSR34').get_text()
    print(rating)
    price = box.find(class_='_1vC4OE').get_text()
    print(price)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because for some products there aren't ratings. This script will substitute missing ratings wit `-`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/exercise-fitness/fitness-equipment/home-gym-combos/pr?sid=qoc,amf,pz0&q=gym+equipments+combo+50+kg&otracker=categorytree')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('div[data-id]'):
    title = div.select('a')[1]['title']
    rating = div.select_one('span[id^="productRating"]')
    if rating:
        rating=rating.text
    else:
        rating='-'
    price = div.select_one('div._1vC4OE').text

    print('{:<15}{:<15}{}'.format(rating, price, title))
```

Prints:

```
3.9            ₹2,499         Star X PVC 50 Kg Weight Combo of 5Ft Rod,Bag and Accessories Home Gym Combo
3.9            ₹3,100         Star X PVC 50KG COMBO WITH 3FT CURL AND 5FT STRAIGHT ROD AND ACCESSORIES Home Gym Combo
4              ₹6,499         Protoner 50 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 5 in 1 foldable bench Home Gym Combo
4              ₹3,498         Protoner 50 kg with Flat Bench Home Gym Fitness Package Home Gym Combo
3.6            ₹19,999        Kobo Single Station Multi Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,744         Venom VNB_DMB_GS_04 Home Gym Combo
3.9            ₹4,133         Protoner 42 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 6 in 1 multi bench Home Gym Combo
3.7            ₹2,599         Star X 50 kg PVC weight with rods and accessories Home Gym Combo
3.6            ₹3,130         Protoner 42 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Flat bench Home Gym Combo
3.3            ₹2,399         Protoner 50 kg PVC weight with 4 rods Home Gym Combo
3.9            ₹1,499         APTITUDE PVC-WL-20KG-WEIGHT-WITH-Straight-and-curl-rod Home Gym Kit Home Gym Combo
-              ₹3,034         Venom Home Gym Set with Curl Rod, Straight Rod, Gym Glvoes & Skipping Rope Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,824         Venom Home Gym Set with Straight Rod, Wrist Band & Hand Gripper Home Gym Combo
3.2            ₹5,499         Protoner 50 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 6 in 1 multi bench Home Gym Combo
3.5            ₹2,349         Protoner 50 kg PVC weight with 3 rods Home Gym Combo
-              ₹4,600         Protoner 44 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 6 in 1 multi bench Home Gym Combo
2.8            ₹3,299         Protoner 46 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Flat bench Home Gym Combo
3.3            ₹2,399         Protoner 48 kg PVC weight with 3 rods Home Gym Combo
4.1            ₹4,720         Protoner 48 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 6 in 1 multi bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹5,965         Protoner 42 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 5 in 1 foldable bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹5,386         Protoner 48 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Preacher curl bench Home Gym Combo
1              ₹3,910         Protoner 42 kg PVC weight with 3in1 bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,505         SPANCO SPC_3C_DMB_50 Home Gym Combo
-              ₹3,211         Venom Home Gym Set with Curl Rod, Straight Rod, Gym Glvoes, Skipping Rope, Sweat Band & Hand Gripper Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,946         Venom Home Gym Set with Curl Rod, Straight Rod & Gym Glvoes Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,927         Venom Home Gym 46 Kg. Home Gym Combo
2.7            ₹3,425         Protoner 50 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Flat bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹3,365         Protoner 48 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Flat bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,175         Protoner 42 kg PVC weight with 3 rods Home Gym Combo
4              ₹7,049         Protoner 46 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 7 in 1 bench Home Gym Combo
2              ₹4,330         Protoner 50 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Preacher curl bench Home Gym Combo
3              ₹7,552         Protoner 48 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 5 in 1 foldable bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹4,090         Protoner 42 kg PVC weight with 4 rods and Preacher curl bench Home Gym Combo
2.2            ₹6,345         Protoner 48 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 7 in 1 bench Home Gym Combo
3.3            ₹2,370         Protoner 44 kg PVC weight with 4 rods Home Gym Combo
-              ₹3,999         Protoner 44 kg PVC home gym with 3in1 bench Home Gym Combo
-              ₹3,123         Venom Home Gym with Curl Rod, Straight Rod, Skipping Rope, Sweat Band & Hand Gripper Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,857         Venom Home Gym Set with Curl Rod & Straight Rod Home Gym Combo
-              ₹2,736         Venom Home Gym Set with Straight Rod & 1 Accessories for Fitness Home Gym Combo
3.7            ₹5,445         Protoner 48 kg pvc weight with 4 rods and 8 in 1 bench Home Gym Combo
```